# XSLT generated SVG with right namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, xml-namespaces

Sorry if I am asking a newbie question, but namespaces are really puzzling to me.

I'm trying to generate a number of SVG documents from a single XML/XSLT.

My stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml" cdata-section-elements="style"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//root/menu"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="menu">
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat(@name,'.svg')"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" id="svg-root" width="482" height="600">
              <defs>
                <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[rect {       
                 fill: white;        
                 fill-opacity:1;
continues...
```

This works and produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" id="svg-root" width="482" height="600">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[rect {       
                     fill: white;        
                     fill-opacity:1;        
continues...
```

But I want to be able to specify height and width attributes based on calculated content

I have tried to create "<svg>" as <xsl:element name="svg"><xsl:attribute name="xmlns">http://www.w3.org/2000/svg </xsl:attribute></xsl:element>

This fails as it (xmlspy) won't let me assign the xmlns attribute.

If I don't specify a namespace on the root (svg), xmlns is automagically added to the root <svg> node and all first-level sub nodes are applied with namespace references like the following (see <defs>)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" id="svg-root" width="482" height="600">
    <defs xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[rect {       
                     fill: white;        
                     fill-opacity:1;        
continues...
```

How can I specify the needed namespaces on the root svg element and at the same time calculate the values for height and width without superfluous namespace references on first-level sub-branches?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Why is calculating the height and width and height causing an issue here?  None of your example code shows anything about that very important point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up attribute-value templates, and read about them.  Use them to calculate the values of height and width instead of using hard-coded values.  So your current literal result element becomes something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="width"
     select="$raw-width * $compression-factor 
             + $fudge"/>            
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     version="1.1" 
     baseProfile="basic" 
     id="svg-root" 
     width="{$width}" 
     height="{$width * 1.61803}">
```

You can also use element and attribute constructors if you like; your attempt to do so went astray because you tried to create a namespace declaration using an xsl:attribute constructor, but the attribute constructor can only create a general attribute, not a namespace attribute.  You would want something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="width"
     select="$raw-width * $compression-factor 
             + $fudge"/>         
<xsl:element name="svg"
             namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <xsl:attribute name="version"
                 select="'1.1'"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="baseProfile"
                 select="'basic'"/> 
  <xsl:attribute name="id"
                 select="'svg-root'"/> 
  <xsl:attribute name="width"
                 select="$width"/> 
  <xsl:attribute name="height"
                 select="$width * 1.61803"/>
```

Comment: n.b. There's no need to use `xsl:element` if the name and namespace are already known. Replacing the `xsl:element` with `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` would work just fine here.

Comment: And the consequence of using xsl:element is, that the other three namespaces gets added to all first-level sub-nodes.
So I go with the first suggestion. Thank you VERY much C.M.